# Closed graph theorem in Simon B.

Tags: operator-theory, closed-graph

[image]

Hello. I have some concern.

**Question 1**. In this version of the closed graph theorem, the mentioned operator is defined as $T:D(T)=X\to Y$?

**Question 2.** If I have have that an operator $T:D(T)\subset X\to Y$, does the theorem not apply to this operator?

**Question 3.** If $D(T)$ is dense in $X$, then is it applicable?

**Question 4**. If $T:D(T)\subset X\to X$ with $D(T)$ dense in $X$, then $T$ is bounded if and only if $T$ closed? For this question, what I have is the following:

$T$ closed $\Rightarrow (D(T),|\cdot |_{T})$ is a Banach space with $|\cdot|_{T}$ graph norm. Now, the operator $T:(D(T),|\cdot|_{T})\to (X,|\cdot|_{X})$ is closed, then by Closed graph theorem, $T:(D(T),|\cdot|_{T})\to (X,|\cdot|_{X})$ is bounded, i.e.
$$|Tx|_{X}\leq C|x|_{T}\text{ for all }x\in D(T)$$
This is equivalent to
$$|Tx|_{X}\leq C(|x|_{X}+|Tx|_{X}),\quad x\in D(T)$$
or
$$|Tx|_{X}\leq \frac{C}{1-C}|x|_{X},\quad x\in D(T)$$
and from here, I would like to see if it is possible to extend the above inequality to all $x\in X$ using the density of $D(T)$ over $X$. Is it possible to do this? Also I don't know if the constant $\frac{C}{1-C}$ is non-negative.

These questions would help me a lot to understand what I am studying.

Thanks.

Comment: Completeness of the domain of $T$ is needed for Closed Graph Theorem.

Comment: then if $T:D(T)\subset X\to Y$+$D(T)$ complete+$X,Y$ Banach spaces  implies that $T$ bounded if and only if $T$ closed? (or does $D(T)$ need to be dense in $X$?)

Comment: If $D(T)$ is closed then it cannot be dense unless it is the whole of $X$. So denseness shoult not come in  at all.

Comment: If $D(T)$ is complete, then it's a Banach space in its own right, so you can forget about the given $X$ and apply the original version of the theorem with $D(T)$ in the role of $X$.